# What does "cut" mean in an American football context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I came across this sentence in a [sports reporting about football](http://www.sandiegouniontribune.com/sports/profootballdoc/sd-sp-pfd-fournette-draft-jaguars-ankle-20170427-story.html):

> Ankle ligament laxity does not inhibit running ability but could affect the ability to **cut** in the manner required of a running back.

What does "cut" mean here? I Googled and found "cut blocking." Same thing?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQRw3zZvb_g

Above is a video showing "running back cuts." To cut in this context means to change direction quickly in an effort to avoid defenders